# Firebug unsets my session in PHP

Tags: php, firebug

I am using the Zebra session class found here http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-session/ to handle all my PHP sessions. I have found a problem that if I have Firebug open, when I navigate to another page in the site I get logged out and the session is dropped.

I also have the addThis toolbar installed.

Otherwise if Firebug is closed the session works perfectly.

Any suggestions on how I could get the session to work with Firebug open?

Comment: i think it unlikely to be a firebug issue. you should eb able to test using another site.

Comment: I wouldnt have thought it was but its only affected when its open. I have the console open to but maybe plusone is affecting it. Dont have any ideas what to do to resolve. I tested using another site and worked fine so back to looking into Zebra Session more. Thanks for the reply